# How do I track a hosted URL on Namecheap.com with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url

I'm hosting a URL with NameCheap, and it is a URL frame for a blogspot.com account. I'm using Google Analytics to track the blogspot.com account, but I'd like to be able to track the NameCheap frame URL as well. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to use the same analytics profile, or a different one?

Comment: I'm stuck on the same problem. I haven't found a way to convince `NameCheap` to let me include Google Analytics (or other scripts) in the iframe wrapper page. Let's say `my_namecheap_url.com` is an iframe wrapper around `my_blogspot_url.com`. I have a Google Analytics tracker on `my_blogspot_url.com`, but Google Analytics believes that ALL referrals to `my_blogspot_url.com` come from  `my_namecheap_url.com`. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track to two Google Analytics accounts it is possible:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-AAAAAAAA-0'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', 'UA-BBBBBBBB-0'],
    ['b._trackPageview']);
```